# PHP : applying html_entity_decode to whole result array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

for security, all data inserted into my MySQL db is cleaned up with 'html_sanitizer'.

data is retrieved using PDO :

```
$statement = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * from table");
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to display the text correctly on the page i use this :

```
echo(html_entity_decode($result[0]['content'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'))
```

this all works correctly.

my question is, what is the best way to apply the 'html_entity_decode' to all of the content of the array?

i'm hoping for something like this :

```
$statement = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * from table");
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = html_entity_decode($result, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); // here is the bit i'm looking for
echo ($result[0]['content'])
```

many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: you can use `array_map` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to apply html_entity_decode() in every field of array If so then array_walk_recursive() is best for this purpose.

```
Example:
$result = array(); // Say Array of your result
array_walk_recursive($result , 'stripFunction');

public function stripFunction(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = html_entity_decode($item, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
```

It apply a user function recursively to every member of an array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php is the reference link of documentation.